# Is it possible to customize or get more ui them in aptana?

Tags: themes, aptana

I would like to change the overall theme or get more choices than the default themes by Aptana. I have it set to the Dark Studio for the overall them but will like to customize it. This is the overall theme not the editor them. Aptana 3.6+

Comment: Some related information on https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/smaller-font-sizes-for-eclipse-on-linux/